# Android SQLite Cursor not null operator strange situation

Tags: android, sqlite, null, operators

I'm just writing a code snippet however it act strangely:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id,name,enabled FROM Reference";
Cursor c = mDatabase.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
    return c;
}
return null;
```

Debugging this code line by line,I noticed that c is not null. and normally code returned null. However cursor value is not logical, i mean select query must return some rows but it doese not do anything. So i changed code like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id,name,enabled FROM Reference";
Cursor c = mDatabase.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
if (c != null) {
    return c;
}
return null;
```

tracing this code again, this time cursor 'c' is not null however snippet returns null!
changing whole snippet to this, fixed problem:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id,name,enabled FROM Reference";
Cursor c = mDatabase.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
if (c == null || c.getCount()<=0) {
    return null;
}
return c;
```

in this case, query returns reasonable number of rows. I'm just wondering what's wrong with first code snippet! is it about using of **!= null** or other things? 
please notice that in first case, cursor count is not reasonable and does not match the database select results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal for the debugger to jump to the last line of a method when exiting the frame. So it seems that the last line is executed while in fact it's another `return` that actually takes place. Inspect the return value at the caller level if you're unsure.

Another thing is that `rawQuery()` will never return a `null` for a `Cursor`.

Comment: So why cursor act strange in first and last snippet? I mean number of returned rows seems different in each of these two snippet... since this is a strange situation i'm just confused!

Comment: The debugger is just confusing you by seemingly jumping to a line when exiting the method frame.

Answer (score 1):

You are not being returned null by the database query. Instead you are recieving an empty cursor. This is a perfectly valid object, like an empty String, and so `c == null` is false. But it also doesn't contain any rows, so `c.getCount()` returns 0.